# Creating A Submenu In Drupal

Tags: routes

Hello I Am New to drupal and i want to create a submenu bar under Menu Navigation So Can ANYONE Suggest And Idea Or Something To Create A Submenu In Other Page Like Shown On Image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Added Image]Submenu can be created by selecting Parent link for that menu and ordering can be done by weights. 
Try reading this in detail at [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/menu)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a dynamic list of links that you want to use in the submenu or those links are always the same?

If your URLs in that submenu don't change, the easiest solution is to manually create a block with submenu links and just place it under the main menu,